# Finding a Weighted Average Based on Years

Tags: r, statistics, average, weighted

I want to create a weighted average of the baseball statistic WAR from 2017 to 2019.
The Averages would go as following:
2019: 57.14%
2018: 28.57%
2017: 14.29%

However some players only played in 2018 and 2019, some having played in 2019 and 2017.
If they've only played in two years it would be 67/33, and only one year would be 100% obviously.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this.
My data set looks like this

```
            Name Season   G  PA HR BB_pct K_pct   ISO  wOBA wRC_plus  Def WAR
337  A.J. Pollock   2017 112 466 14    7.5  15.2 0.205 0.340      103  2.6 2.2
357  A.J. Pollock   2018 113 460 21    6.7  21.7 0.228 0.338      111  0.9 2.6
191 Aaron Altherr   2017 107 412 19    7.8  25.2 0.245 0.359      120 -7.9 1.4
162   Aaron Hicks   2017  88 361 15   14.1  18.6 0.209 0.363      128  6.4 3.4
186   Aaron Hicks   2018 137 581 27   15.5  19.1 0.219 0.360      129  2.3 5.0
464   Aaron Hicks   2019  59 255 12   12.2  28.2 0.208 0.325      102  1.3 1.1
```

And the years vary from person to person, but was wondering if anyone had a way to do this weighted average dependent on the years they played. I also dont want any only 2017-ers if that make sense.

Comment: How should your expected output looks like?

Comment: like another column with a weighted WAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, there is an easy way of doing your task. Unfortunately my approach is a little bit more complex. I'm using `dplyr` and `purr`.

First I put those weights into a list:

```r
one_year  <- 1
two_years <- c(2/3, 1/3)
three_years <- c(4/7, 3/7, 1/7)
weights <- list(one_year, two_years, three_years)
```

Next I split the datset into a list by the number of seasons each player took part:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(n=n()) %>%
  arrange(n) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_split(n) -> my_list
```

Now I define a function that calculates the average using the weights:

```r
WAR_average <- function(i) {my_list[[i]] %>% 
                              group_by(Name) %>% 
                              mutate(WAR_average = sum(WAR * weights[[i]]))}
```

And finally I apply the function `WAR_average` on `my_list` and filter/select the data:

```r
my_list %>%
  seq_along() %>%
  lapply(WAR_average) %>%             # apply function
  reduce(rbind) %>%                   # bind the dataframes into one df
  filter(Season != 2017 | n != 1) %>% # filter players only active in 2017 
  select(Name, WAR_average) %>%       # select player and war_average
  distinct()                          # remove duplicates
```

This whole process returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   Name [2]
  Name         WAR_average
  <chr>              <dbl>
1 A.J. Pollock        2.33
2 Aaron Hicks         4.24
```